# Python Hydra - Is this possible to list config and yaml file?

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, fb-hydra

I have below file hirarchy from which i want to list config path and yaml files

```
Main_dir:
 conf:
  project:
    test_project1:
      env:
        source:
            src.yaml
        dest:
            dest.yaml
        test_dir1.yaml
        test_dir2.yaml
```

i tried using below compose api,

```
with initialize(version_base=None, config_path="../../conf"):
 cfg = compose(config_name="config", overrides = ["project=test_project1"])
 print(cfg)
```

but it didn't give the exepected output

#Expected:
It should list all config path and yaml file from the test_project1

```
source:
 src.yaml
dest:
 dest.yaml
test_dir1.yaml
test_dir2.yaml
```

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a fun fundamental misunderstanding of what the Compose API is doing.
Hydra is composing a config object from multiple configs. Not listing them.
If you need to list the configs, you should be using a different tool/API.